# Azure, default "Hey, Java developers!" welcome page after successfully deployment

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

After succesfully deployment via Github repo of my Spring boot Application in Azure's App Service i have still "Hey java developers!" page, i tried do this via Github and Github Actions, Github and Kudu, FTP, but result is allways the same. I'm out of ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your github project or the content of your webapp using Kudu?

Comment: Pls try my way, it works for me.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Ah hi, and sorry for late response, i tried the way similar to Your's before, and that didn't solve that. 
And... this is weird, and i don't know completely whats happened - After few hours of trying to fix that, i just left this for a night-time and on the morning was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Today, I try again. I disconnect connection. And try to reconnect, I saw build area like below.

[image]

After `Action` completed, it works.

**So I suggest you disconnect and reconnect to solve the problem.**

**PRIVIOUS**

According to your description, I personally tested one side and your problem reappeared.

**My troubleshooting steps:**

1. First create a default page for webapp. (Under windows, it fails, indicating that this is not).
2. Deploy the webapp under linux and find that everything is normal.

From the Action on github, it was found that there should be a problem with the build in the deployment under windows.

**In conclusion:**

It is recommended to use linux to deploy webapp. As for the deployment failure under windows, it is recommended to [raise a support ticket for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

**My test result.**

Under Linux, after build action, we can see `app.jar` file under wwwroot folder.

[image]

[image]

I also move it to windows webapp, it doesn't work.