# How to avoid getting stuck on the "Hey, Java Developers" AFTER deployment of a Spring Boot App on Azure

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm a huge Azure beginner, and I've been having an issue for some time, that when I try to deploy my spring boot application to Azure, it doesn't seem to do anything? It's configured to work with GitHub actions, and shows active when new content is committed, but nothing seems to appear.

The system uses Java Spring Boot backend and ReactJS for frontend.

I'm using a regular Azure Web App as opposed to the spring specific one because it costs too much money to run once up.

Any help would really be appreciated as I'm not sure what to do
[This displays no matter what I seem to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K94qn.png)

[It should be displaying the web app as instructed by index.js, which is the default document that we have entered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ol6.png)

Happy to answer any questions, as I'm not sure what information is applicable to this case.

Thanks

I've tried changing the Tomcat version displayed to 3.4.10 as mentioned in : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974

And changing the default documents as mentioned in : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1295335/how-to-successfully-deploy-source-code-from-azure

And reconnecting as mentioned in : [Azure, default "Hey, Java developers!" welcome page after successfully deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217018/azure-default-hey-java-developers-welcome-page-after-successfully-deploymen)

Comment: Can you share your project repository, if available in GitHub (only if it doesn't have any sensitive information).

Comment: I would suggest the steps on this QuickStart tut, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?pivots=java-maven-tomcat#3---configure-the-maven-plugin and please let me know on which stage you encounter any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Azure App Service=>Advanced Tools=>go=> redirects to KUDU site`.

- If the app is windows, Navigate to `Debug Console=>CMD=>Site/wwwroot`,  check if all the required files of your project deployed and available.
- If the app is Linux, add newui to the KUDU site URL (https://kpspringreactapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui), open `site/wwwroot`and check if the deployed project files are available.
- Go to your Web App=> App Service Logs=>Enable Application Logging.

[image]

- Run the application and check the logs in `Log Stream`  of your Azure App Service if there are any errors that may be causing the application to stop running.

[image]

- **If still doesn't work, deploy the application to Azure App Service using File Zilla. Refer the [document](https://dev.to/strivedi4u/springboot-reactjs-web-application-deploy-on-azure-32hf#:%7E:text=SpringBoot%20+%20ReactJs%20Web%20Application%20Deploy%20on%20Azure,Paste%20these%20details%20in%20FileZila%20...%20More%20items) explained by *Shashank Trivedi*.**

Steps to deploy the Application with SpringBoot Backend and ReactJs Frontend to Azure:

- Install **FireZilla**.
- Create and open Azure App Service and click on **Stop**.
- Navigate to Deployment Center=>FTPS credentials, copy `FTPS endpoint, Username, Password`.
- Open Firezilla, paste the values and establish the connection and upload the WAR/JAR file of your application.

[image]

- After uploading the files, start your Azure App Service and run the application.